# numpy.fromfunction with specified non-arange-like array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, numpy-ndarray

I have defined a function;

```
def f(x,y):
    return (1+x)**3.2 * np.cos(y**2.31+x)
```

and have the following two arrays:

```
x = np.linspace(10,20,10)
y = np.linspace(5,8,5)
```

Now I wish to create a 10 x 5 matrix where each (i,j) element is given by `f(x[i],x[j])`.
This is easily achieved with a for loop:

```
result = np.zeros(len(x)*len(y)).reshape((len(x),len(y)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        result[i][j] = f(x[i],y[j])
```

However, I want to significantly increase computation time so I am looking for a non-for loop approach.
It would seem that `np.fromfunction` brings me partly there:

```
result = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: f(x,y), (10, 5), dtype=int)
```

However, this takes x and y to be arange-like, i.e. this takes elements x = 0,1,...,9 and y = 0,1,...,4.
Is there a way to tell this function that I want it to take my previously defined arrays for x and y.
If this is not possible with `np.fromfunction`, is there another way to achieve the same result I get with my for loop, but with less computation time?

Comment: can you define your function `f` ?

Comment: Certainly. See the edited question. It's a complicated function with cosines and powers. This is just an example as the real function I use is even more complicated.

Comment: `fromfunction` is not a substitute for loops!  It only works if your function already works with whole arrays.  I know the docs can be confusing, especially if you come with preconceived notions, but when in doubt, look at the code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is written so it accepts whole arrays, you can just pass the `x` and `y` so they `broadcast` together.

```
In [472]: x = np.linspace(10,20,10) 
     ...: y = np.linspace(5,8,5)                                                               
In [473]: def f(x,y): 
     ...:     return (1-x)**3.2 * np.cos(y**2.31+x) 
     ...:
```

Make `x` (10,1) array which then broadcasts with the (5,) `y` to give a (10,5) result:

```
In [474]: f(x[:,None], y)                                                                      
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

Out[474]: 
array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

All `fromfunction` does is generate `indices` and pass them to your function:

```
In [478]: np.indices((3,4))                                                                    
Out[478]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
#function(*indices...)
```

If your function expects values, not the `i,j` indices `fromfunction` does nothing for you!.  it just forces you to use the extra layer of indexing
`f(x[i],y[j])`.   If your function handle arrays, `fromfunction` does not speed up the calculations.  And if your function can only accept scalar, `fromfunction` does not work at all.

Why the `nan`?

```
In [489]: f(x[0],y[0])                                                                         
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Out[489]: nan
```

===

With the corrected `f`:

```
In [494]: def f(x,y): 
     ...:     return (1+x)**3.2 * np.cos(y**2.31+x) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [495]: x,y                                                                                  
Out[495]: 
(array([10.        , 11.11111111, 12.22222222, 13.33333333, 14.44444444,
        15.55555556, 16.66666667, 17.77777778, 18.88888889, 20.        ]),
 array([5.  , 5.75, 6.5 , 7.25, 8.  ]))
```

`ix_` can be used to add the broadcasting dimension to `x`:

```
In [496]: np.ix_(x,y)                                                                          
Out[496]: 
(array([[10.        ],
        [11.11111111],
        [12.22222222],
        [13.33333333],
        [14.44444444],
        [15.55555556],
        [16.66666667],
        [17.77777778],
        [18.88888889],
        [20.        ]]), 
 array([[5.  , 5.75, 6.5 , 7.25, 8.  ]]))
```

And those arrays can then be passed to `f` (as I did in  [474]):

```
In [497]: f(*np.ix_(x,y))                                                                      
Out[497]: 
array([[  1322.50123614,  -1353.39115671,  -1702.96842965,
          2039.59858593,   2149.99822839],
       [ -1268.79441897,   1220.20345147,    572.47038806,
           401.57578676,   1322.04810644],
       [ -3873.89288421,   3872.45293387,   3741.19176848,
         -3203.15416244,  -2320.43820171],
       [ -2274.83634272,   2356.4885057 ,   3316.20257628,
         -4368.07920439,  -4932.15975126],
       [  3805.32723978,  -3710.95441159,  -2413.75855025,
           343.98082438,  -1742.79381001],
       [  7825.16462628,  -7850.07869311,  -7934.59775682,
          7309.08041012,   5891.07144208],
       [  2696.9980712 ,  -2869.31389573,  -4956.11491324,
          7455.17663401,   9114.69519122],
       [ -8800.47513177,   8651.89940176,   6527.58767232,
         -2896.13626079,   1015.66697767],
       [-13326.47899275,  13419.77502789,  14202.98227539,
        -13981.08503081, -12233.58338808],
       [ -1484.09855587,   1795.12675239,   5660.63236478,
        -10620.54747276, -14370.53381538]])
```

Applied to 3 arrays:

```
In [503]: np.ix_([100,200],[10,20,30],[1,2,3,4])                                               
Out[503]: 
(array([[[100]],

        [[200]]]), array([[[10],
         [20],
         [30]]]), array([[[1, 2, 3, 4]]]))
```

produces a (2,1,1), (1,3,1) and (1,1,4) arrays, which would broadcast together to produce a (2,3,4) result.

```
def ff(x,y,z): return x+y+z  
In [504]: ff(*_)                                                                               
Out[504]: 
array([[[111, 112, 113, 114],
        [121, 122, 123, 124],
        [131, 132, 133, 134]],

       [[211, 212, 213, 214],
        [221, 222, 223, 224],
        [231, 232, 233, 234]]])
```

Comment: The `nan` is due to 1-x being negative in my example, making the (1-x)**3.2 complex. Changing this to (1+x)**3.2 fixes this. I shall update my post account for to this.

Comment: Also, this is a simplified version of my problem. In truth, my function looks more complicated than this (e.g. it takes actually 4 input values instead of 2), leading to much more complications that make `np.fromfunction` perhaps less appealing. And it isn't as evident as to how I could use the broadcasting you describe for more than 2 input values. I think I'd best just explain these complications in a new post.

Comment: @TheOne. You should still figure out how to properly vectorize your code. Post the real function if you need to. Calling `fromfunction` will run a glorified for loop for you under the hood.

Comment: I've added an `np.ix_` example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i, j:  f(x[i],y[j]), (len(x),len(y)), dtype=int)
```

you have to specify `dtype=int` otherwise the data-type of the coordinate will be `float` which can not be used as indices in `f(x[i],y[j])`